# Not able to get post data from ajax call - wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have an Ajax call loading more posts onto a page. Everything works and I get the HTML back from the template that I have but it's missing all the of post information so it's just the html skeleton.

I'm using the same template to load the first posts onto the page but then when using the ajax call, I can't get the Wordpress methods to display back the data.

When I var dump on my template php file, I can see all of the post information but it doesn't come through back to the inline php.

Loading the Posts:

```
foreach (load_posts($offset) as $post) {
    include(locate_template('_includes/loop-archive-single.php'));
}
```

The Template:

```
<li>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__bd">
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="feature__media">
                    <a class="imgLink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_field('media_image') ?>" alt="<?php the_field('media_image') ?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="feature__hd">
                    <h2 class="hdg hdg--lg">
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="feature__bd">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Am I outside the loop or what's going on? I'd like to keep the template that way it is right now. Again, the post data is there, but it just won't show through the_permalink() or the_field('media_image') and anything like that...

Comment: Ack! Why aren't you using `get_template_part`?  Also, are you doing AJAX the [WordPress Way](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? Lastly, is `load_posts` getting anything? That's not a WP function (that I am aware of), so I'm strongly suspecting you are doing things outside of the WordPress structure.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the ID on ajax call ... of which post you need

change the template file to

```
<li>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__bd">
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="feature__media">
                    <a class="imgLink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_field('media_image',$post_ID) ?>" alt="<?php the_field('media_image',$postID) ?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="feature__hd">
                    <h2 class="hdg hdg--lg">
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink($postID); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="feature__bd">
                    <?php the_excerpt($postID); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```